# nginx ingress rewrite-target problem with redirection

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Kibana dashboard that I currently access through the root of my host : `https://my.host.com/`. I want to change it so I can access it through the path `https://my.host.com/kibana/`. For this, I used the `rewrite-target` annotation as provided in the [main documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kibana-ing
  annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: kibana-ingress-class
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /kibana(/|$)(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: kibana-svc
              servicePort: 5601
```

I think this works to some extent because when hitting https://my.host.com/kibana/, I get redirected to the login page. But the login page is returned to my browser without the kibana prefix : `https://my.host.com/app/login` and I get a 404.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**

This is currently what is happening when I hit `https://my.host.com/kibana/` :

[image]

This sends back a HTTP 302 with a redirection to `app/login` as you can see in the **Location** header. But when my browser asks back Nginx to fetch for this app/login, it rightfully gives a 404 since this path is unkown to it.

Is there a way (through an Ingress annotation maybe) to append the '/kibana' prefix to all the **Location** headers that are being returned?

**EDIT2:**

I managed to append the `/kibana/` part in the **Location** header by adding these 2 annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-from: "/"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-redirect-to: "/kibana/"
```

This makes the redirection point to `kibana/app/login`, resulting in a 200 status. However more objects are being loaded by the page like a bootsrap.js and their location are hardcoded within the html page being sent back like this:

```
</script><script src="/bootstrap.js"></script></body></html>
```

Obviously this hits back with another 404 error on my browser end... I think I will have to deal with this on the application end instead.

Comment: Have you installed ingress controller ?  Can you provide more information about your setup and steps you have followed so far ?

Comment: Yes my Nginx Ingress controller is up and running. As I said my setup was working when my path was simply : `path : /` but I can't make it work anymore since switching to `path: /kibana(/|$)(.*)`. I'm running on version v1.18 of k8s and v0.27 of Nginx controller (Tried to upgrade to v0.44.0 but same issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix this at the application level. In my `kibana.yml` config file, I had to tell Kibana that it was running behind a reverse proxy. So I set `server.basePath: /kibana`.

Note that the configuration I made above for the Ingress is still needed, as the application is still reacheable at the root of server but only the responses URLs will include the `/kibana/` prefix.